# MySQLI query not returning results

Tags: mysqli

Everyone keeps saying to switch to mysqli so I'm working on changing my site over now, but all my content is gone from doing so.

```
 $mysqli = mysqli_connect("$server", "$user", "$pass", "$webdb");
    $query=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE name='Index'");
    $result = mysqli_query($webdb, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
                {
                echo $row->content;
            }
            ?>
```

My Variables are correctly set; the format looks correct from everywhere I look, but the content area is empty when it's not empty in my actual Server. Does anyone see a flaw here that I need to correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the result from your first query to `$query`. Then you pass `$query` (which is not a string query, but a result object) to yet another `mysqli_query()` call. Also, `$webdb` should be `$mysqli` .. Maybe you meant to do

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE name='Index'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer on this and sorry for the belated reply! Knowing a little more now has been a massive help and looking at it now. I understand the downvote on it!

Comment: Glad you're getting a grip on it. Not sure why it was downvoted.. I'll counter with an upvote ;)